# Were korbanos olah prohibited?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, korban, joshua--book-of, mishkan-tabernacle

Abarbanel on Joshua 13:14 explains the verse:

> official translation from chabad.org:
>
> Only to the tribe of Levi he gave no inheritance; the sacrifices of the Lord God of Israel made by fire are his inheritance, as He said to him.

Abarbanel learns the verse compares the inheritance of Levi to fire offerings, in the following sense. While the *Mishkan* wasn't in a permanent place, the fire-offerings were prohibited. Only after the *Mishkan* is set in a permanent spot, do the fire-offerings become allowed.

So too, Yehoshua gave the cities reserved for the tribe of Levi after the *Mishkan* was in a permanent place.

This seems to imply the fire-offerings (I assume *korbanos olah*) were prohibited during the conquest of the land? This sounds like an odd conclusion, did I understand it correctly?

Thank you very much